# XNA Skinned Model - Keyframe.Bone out of range exception

Tags: xna-4.0, skeletal-animation

I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeException on this line of AnimationPlayer.cs:
`boneTransforms[keyframe.Bone] = keyframe.Transform;`

I don't get what it's really referring to. The error happens when keyframe.Bone is 14, but I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. The 14th bone of my model? What would that even be? I read [this thread](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/18771/200938.aspx), but nothing there seemed to work. I don't have many bones, stray edges/verts, unassigned verts, unparented/non-root bones, or bones with dots in the name. What else can I be missing?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. It was because I was trying to call two animations with different lengths for the same AnimationClip. I had a `Move` class that would run animations for the correlating model based on a name parameter, 'Walk' in this case--there should've been two different instances of `Move`, even if they both use the same animation name.